# Using censusdata api, how to fix the max entried exceeded with url error

Tags: python, census

This code works on another computer but not on the one I have been using for downloading census data. I am getting this error:

```
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.census.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2012/acs/acs5?get=NAME,B24123_377E,B24123_378E,B24123_379E,B24123_380E,B24123_381E,B24123_382E,B24123_38

3E,B24123_384E,B24123_385E,B24123_386E,B24123_387E,B24123_388E,B24123_389E,B24123_390E,B24123_391E,B

24123_392E,B24123_393E,B24123_394E,B24123_395E,B24123_396E,B24123_397E,B24123_398E,B24123_399E,B2412

3_400E,B24123_401E,B24123_402E,B24123_403E,B24123_404E,B24123_405E,B24123_406E,B24123_407E,B24123_40

8E,B24123_409E,B24123_410E,B24123_411E,B24123_412E,B24123_413E,B24123_414E,B24123_415E,B24123_416E,B

24123_417E,B24123_418E,B24123_419E,B24123_420E,B24123_421E,B24123_422E,B24123_423E,B24123_424E,B2412

3_425E&for=tract:*&in=state:01+county:*&key=e39a53c23358c749629da6f31d8f03878d4088d6 (Caused by

SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import censusdata
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
#import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import censusgeocode as cg
import numpy as np
from numbers import Number
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import requests
import pandas
import geopandas
import json
import math
from haversine import haversine
from ipfn import ipfn
import networkx
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import patheffects
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString

variable_list1 = [
'B24123_377E',
'B24123_378E',
'B24123_379E',
'B24123_380E',
'B24123_381E',
'B24123_382E',
'B24123_383E',
'B24123_384E',
'B24123_385E',
'B24123_386E',
'B24123_387E',
'B24123_388E',
'B24123_389E',
'B24123_390E',
'B24123_391E',
'B24123_392E',
'B24123_393E',
'B24123_394E',
'B24123_395E',
'B24123_396E',
'B24123_397E',
'B24123_398E',
'B24123_399E',
'B24123_400E',
'B24123_401E',
'B24123_402E',
'B24123_403E',
'B24123_404E',
'B24123_405E',
'B24123_406E',
'B24123_407E',
'B24123_408E',
'B24123_409E',
'B24123_410E',
'B24123_411E',
'B24123_412E',
'B24123_413E',
'B24123_414E',
'B24123_415E',
'B24123_416E',
'B24123_417E',
'B24123_418E',
'B24123_419E',
'B24123_420E',
'B24123_421E',
'B24123_422E',
'B24123_423E',
'B24123_424E',
'B24123_425E',
'B24123_426E',
'B24123_427E',
'B24123_428E',
'B24123_429E',
'B24123_430E',
'B24123_431E',
'B24123_432E',
'B24123_433E',
'B24123_434E',
'B24123_435E',
'B24123_436E',
'B24123_437E',
'B24123_438E',
'B24123_439E',
'B24123_440E',
'B24123_441E',
'B24123_442E',
'B24123_443E',
'B24123_444E',
'B24123_445E',
'B24123_446E',
'B24123_447E',
'B24123_448E',
'B24123_449E',
'B24123_450E',
'B24123_451E',
'B24123_452E',
'B24123_453E',
'B24123_454E',
'B24123_455E',
'B24123_456E',
'B24123_457E',
'B24123_458E',
'B24123_459E',
'B24123_460E',
'B24123_461E',
'B24123_462E',
'B24123_463E',
'B24123_464E',
'B24123_465E',
'B24123_466E',
'B24123_467E',
'B24123_468E',
'B24123_469E',
'B24123_470E',
'B24123_471E',
'B24123_472E',
'B24123_473E',
'B24123_474E',
'B24123_475E',
'B24123_476E',
'B24123_477E',
'B24123_478E',
'B24123_479E',
'B24123_480E',
'B24123_481E',
'B24123_482E',
'B24123_483E',
'B24123_484E',
'B24123_485E',
'B24123_486E',
'B24123_487E',
'B24123_488E',
'B24123_489E',
'B24123_490E',
'B24123_491E',
'B24123_492E',
'B24123_493E',
'B24123_494E',
'B24123_495E',
'B24123_496E',
'B24123_497E',
'B24123_498E',
'B24123_499E',
'B24123_500E',
'B24123_501E',
'B24123_502E',
'B24123_503E',
'B24123_504E',
'B24123_505E',
'B24123_506E',
'B24123_507E',
'B24123_508E',
'B24123_509E',
'B24123_510E',
'B24123_511E',
'B24123_512E',
'B24123_513E',
'B24123_514E',
'B24123_515E',
'B24123_516E',
'B24123_517E',
'B24123_518E',
'B24123_519E',
'B24123_520E',
'B24123_521E',
'B24123_522E',
'B24123_523E',
'B24123_524E',
'B24123_525E',
'B24123_526E',
'B24124_001E',
'B24124_002E',
'B24124_003E',
'B24124_004E',
'B24124_005E',
'B24124_006E',
'B24124_007E',
'B24124_008E',
'B24124_009E',
'B24124_010E',
'B24124_011E',
'B24124_012E',
'B24124_013E',
'B24124_014E',
'B24124_015E',
'B24124_016E',
'B24124_017E',
'B24124_018E',
'B24124_019E',
'B24124_020E',
'B24124_021E',
'B24124_022E',
'B24124_023E',
'B24124_024E',
'B24124_025E',
'B24124_026E',
'B24124_027E',
'B24124_028E',
'B24124_029E',
'B24124_030E',
'B24124_031E',
'B24124_032E',
'B24124_033E',
'B24124_034E',
'B24124_035E',
'B24124_036E',
'B24124_037E',
'B24124_038E',
'B24124_039E',
'B24124_040E',
'B24124_041E',
'B24124_042E',
'B24124_043E',
'B24124_044E',
'B24124_045E',
'B24124_046E',
'B24124_047E',
'B24124_048E',
]
variable_list2 = [
'B24124_049E',
'B24124_050E',
'B24124_051E',
'B24124_052E',
'B24124_053E',
'B24124_054E',
'B24124_055E',
'B24124_056E',
'B24124_057E',
'B24124_058E',
'B24124_059E',
'B24124_060E',
'B24124_061E',
'B24124_062E',
'B24124_063E',
'B24124_064E',
'B24124_065E',
'B24124_066E',
'B24124_067E',
'B24124_068E',
'B24124_069E',
'B24124_070E',
'B24124_071E',
'B24124_072E',
'B24124_073E',
'B24124_074E',
'B24124_075E',
'B24124_076E',
'B24124_077E',
'B24124_078E',
'B24124_079E',
'B24124_080E',
'B24124_081E',
'B24124_082E',
'B24124_083E',
'B24124_084E',
'B24124_085E',
'B24124_086E',
'B24124_087E',
'B24124_088E',
'B24124_089E',
'B24124_090E',
'B24124_091E',
'B24124_092E',
'B24124_093E',
'B24124_094E',
'B24124_095E',
'B24124_096E',
'B24124_097E',
'B24124_098E',
'B24124_099E',
'B24124_100E',
'B24124_101E',
'B24124_102E',
'B24124_103E',
'B24124_104E',
'B24124_105E',
'B24124_106E',
'B24124_107E',
'B24124_108E',
'B24124_109E',
'B24124_110E',
'B24124_111E',
'B24124_112E',
'B24124_113E',
'B24124_114E',
'B24124_115E',
'B24124_116E',
'B24124_117E',
'B24124_118E',
'B24124_119E',
'B24124_120E',
'B24124_121E',
'B24124_122E',
'B24124_123E',
'B24124_124E',
'B24124_125E',
'B24124_126E',
'B24124_127E',
'B24124_128E',
'B24124_129E',
'B24124_130E',
'B24124_131E',
'B24124_132E',
'B24124_133E',
'B24124_134E',
'B24124_135E',
'B24124_136E',
'B24124_137E',
'B24124_138E',
'B24124_139E',
'B24124_140E',
'B24124_141E',
'B24124_142E',
'B24124_143E',
'B24124_144E',
'B24124_145E',
'B24124_146E',
'B24124_147E',
'B24124_148E',
'B24124_149E',
'B24124_150E',
'B24124_151E',
'B24124_152E',
'B24124_153E',
'B24124_154E',
'B24124_155E',
'B24124_156E',
'B24124_157E',
'B24124_158E',
'B24124_159E',
'B24124_160E',
'B24124_161E',
'B24124_162E',
'B24124_163E',
'B24124_164E',
'B24124_165E',
'B24124_166E',
'B24124_167E',
'B24124_168E',
'B24124_169E',
'B24124_170E',
'B24124_171E',
'B24124_172E',
'B24124_173E',
'B24124_174E',
'B24124_175E',
'B24124_176E',
'B24124_177E',
'B24124_178E',
'B24124_179E',
'B24124_180E',
'B24124_181E',
'B24124_182E',
'B24124_183E',
'B24124_184E',
'B24124_185E',
'B24124_186E',
'B24124_187E',
'B24124_188E',
'B24124_189E',
'B24124_190E',
'B24124_191E',
'B24124_192E',
'B24124_193E',
'B24124_194E',
'B24124_195E',
'B24124_196E',
'B24124_197E',
'B24124_198E',
'B24124_199E',
'B24124_200E',
'B24124_201E',
'B24124_202E',
'B24124_203E',
'B24124_204E',
'B24124_205E',
'B24124_206E',
'B24124_207E',
'B24124_208E',
'B24124_209E',
'B24124_210E',
'B24124_211E',
'B24124_212E',
'B24124_213E',
'B24124_214E',
'B24124_215E',
'B24124_216E',
'B24124_217E',
'B24124_218E',
'B24124_219E',
'B24124_220E',
'B24124_221E',
'B24124_222E',
'B24124_223E',
'B24124_224E',
'B24124_225E',
'B24124_226E',
'B24124_227E',
'B24124_228E',
'B24124_229E',
'B24124_230E',
'B24124_231E',
'B24124_232E',
'B24124_233E',
'B24124_234E',
'B24124_235E',
'B24124_236E',
'B24124_237E',
'B24124_238E',
'B24124_239E',
'B24124_240E',
'B24124_241E',
'B24124_242E',
'B24124_243E',
'B24124_244E',
'B24124_245E',
'B24124_246E',
'B24124_247E',
'B24124_248E',
'B24124_249E',
'B24124_250E',
'B24124_251E',
]

all_variable_lists = [variable_list1, variable_list2]
print(len(all_variable_lists[0]))
#2) For each year, download the relevant variables for each tract
def download_year(year,variable_list,State,County,Tract):
    df = censusdata.download('acs5', year, censusdata.censusgeo([('state',State),('county',County),('tract',Tract)]), variable_list, key = 'e39a53c23358c749629da6f31d8f03878d4088d6')
    df['Year']=str(year)
    return df
#3) Define function to download for a single year and state 
def callback_arg(i,variable_list,year):
    try:        
        print('Downloading - ',year,'State', i,' of 57')
        if i<10:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,'0'+str(i),'*','*')
            return df
        if i==51:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,str(i),'*','*')
            return df
        else:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,str(i),'*','*')
            return df
    except:
        pass

#3) Function to download for all states and all years, do some slight formatting
def download_all_data(variable_list,max_year):
    df=download_year(2012,variable_list,'01','*','*')
    for year in range(2012,max_year+1):
        if year == 2012:
            for i in range(0,57):
                df=df.append(callback_arg(i,variable_list,year))
        else: 
            for i in range(0,57):
                df=df.append(callback_arg(i,variable_list,year))
    df2=df.reset_index()
    df2=df2.rename(columns = {"index": "Location+Type"}).astype(str)
    df2['state']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(', ').str[2]
    df2['Census_tract']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(',').str[0].str.split(' ').str[2][0]
    df2['County_name']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(', ').str[1]
    return(df2)
#4) Some slight formatting
def write_to_csv(df2,name = 'Employment Data Part 9'):
    df2.to_csv(name)
#5) The line below is commented out, but should run the entire download sequence

list_of_dfs = []
for var_list in all_variable_lists:
    list_of_dfs.append(download_all_data(var_list, 2018))
x1 = list_of_dfs[0].reset_index()
x2 = list_of_dfs[1].reset_index()
x3 = pd.merge(x1,x2, on=['index','Location+Type','Year','state','Census_tract','County_name'])
write_to_csv(x3)
```

The code above will work on your machine once you download the dependencies. What I want to know is how to get this error resolved. There does not seem to be any solution on the internet for this particular api so I thought it would be useful to make a post about this. I also made a post on the github issues section for this api.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have run into the same problem.

Comment: @jtam no I have not yet, will let you know if I do.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Using `sleep(60)` has solved it.

```
import time

time.sleep(60)
```